# Google Bookmarks search for tags "a" OR "b"?

Tags: google-bookmarks

If I want to make a search for bookmarks that has the tags "a" and "b", I would do a search for `label:"a" "b"`.

However how do I do more advanced searches like a search for tags "a" OR "b" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`label:a OR label:b` should work.

Comment: way to go, brilliant !